# Changing Font Awesome Icon Link color after it's :visited

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, font-awesome, visited

Just trying to change some FA Icons a:visited color from the default blue. Giving me a hell of a time for some reason. All I want is to change the links color from blue after it is visited. Here is the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="pull-right" id="socialMediaIcons">
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-3x"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#socialMediaIcons .fa a:link, #socialMediaIcons .fa a:visited  {
    color: #ccc;
}
#socialMediaIcons .fa:hover, #socialMediaIcons .fa:focus {
    color: #ccc;
    border: none;
}
#socialMediaIcons .fa {
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
}
```

Everything is seeming to have an effect except the `#socialMediaIcons .fa a:link, #socialMediaIcons .fa a:visited` part. Just want to change color of visited link.

Comment: It look like wrong selectors, the `a` is not inside `.fa`, you can just use `a:link`, `a:visited` etc, remember the order LoVe HAte.

Comment: I figured something was out of order. Thanks for showing me that mnemonic! I never heard that LoVe HAte one before, and will forever use it in the future!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
#socialMediaIcons a:link .fa, #socialMediaIcons a:visited .fa  {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Your `.fa` is inside of the `a` and thus have to be after the `a:visited` in the selector.

Comment: That did it, thanks! As you and Pangloss pointed out, my CSS was out of wack. I wrestled with it for way too long, so this one second simple solution is very helpful! Appreciate it! I'll approve the answer as soon as I can in 3 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems as though you were targeting out of scope, the `a`'s aren't the children of `.fa`, it's the other way around.

Try the following:

```
#socialMediaIcons a:visited > .fa  {
    color: #ccc;
}
```